# calculate percent to total by combining 2 SQL aggregate functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to calculate the number of duplicates in 'mktcoupons' and generate the percent of the duplicates so that the sum of all the percentages equal to one. However, I am getting zeros for all my percentages. Any suggestion? Thanks.

```
select mktcoupons, count(*) as countof, 
    count(*)/(select count(*) from X) as percentage
from X
group by mktcoupons
```

The result looks like:

```
mktcoupons  countof percentage
1   2334909 0
2   2725208 0
3   224979  0
4   24987   0
5   2032    0
6   341     0
7   62      0
8   13      0
9   5       0
10  1       0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server does integer division.  You can explicit convert the values to a numeric with decimal points.  I often just multiply by 1.0:

```
select mktcoupons, count(*) as countof, 
    count(*)/(select 1.0*count(*) from X) as percentage
from X
group by mktcoupons;
```

That said, you don't need a subquery for this query.  You can use window functions instead:

```
select mktcoupons, count(*) as countof, 
       count(*)/sum(1.0 * count(*)) over () as percentage
from X
group by mktcoupons;
```

This is particularly helpful when you have a complicated `WHERE` clause or `JOIN`s that you would have to duplicate in the subquery.

Comment: Thanks! Both of your queries work wonderfully! I am still trying to figure out why count(*) needs to be multiplied by 1.0. (Count(*) from X) returns an integer. Does multiplying an integer by 1.0 makes it "more integer"?

Comment: @May . . . SQL Server does integer arithmetic on integers, so 3/2  = 1, not 1.5.  This affects averages as well as division.  The multiplication by 1.0 (or better yet an explicit conversion) converts it to a number that has a decimal place.

Comment: @Gordon...Thanks! Now that I understand why, I changed the part of my query of calculating the percentage to (1.0*count(*))/(select count(*) from X) and it worked too. So looks like I can either multiplying the denominator or the numerator by 1.0 to make this trick work!